# Conversion from POST to GET

Tags: sql-injection

I am trying to hack Kioptrix VM #4 without using SQLmap. I have found the injection point. But the web application is such that it does not display the parameters in the URL. I get the parameters in Burp proxy. Burp can covert POST into GET too. But then the injection does not work (in GET method).

SQLMap works fine with the command below:

```
sqlmap -u "http://192.168.118.139/checklogin.php" --dbms=MySQL --level=5 --risk=3 --data="myusername=admin&mypassword='" --dump
```

But in my attacking machine's browser, the URL `http://192.168.118.139/checklogin.php?myusername=admin&mypassword=` does not inflict SQL injection. Hence, I cannot do SQL injection manually, without using SQLMap.

Any idea, gurus?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `curl`, which is a general-purpose command-line http client. See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

You can make a POST request with `curl`, by setting its `--data` option.

```
curl --data="myusername=admin&mypassword='" "http://192.168.118.139/checklogin.php"
```

Comment: Yes, curl works fine with the above options. However, my main purpose is to detect SQL Injection point. For that I need a command.

Comment: Well, I make it a policy not to teach people methods of hacking into websites on Stack Overflow, because I don't know you and I don't know if you're truly doing this for innocent reasons. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Bill. My policy is not to argue in Internet forum.